# How to put image into AutoPurgingImageCache after af_setImageWithURL completed?

Tags: ios, image, swift, caching, alamofire

I want to use `imageView.af_setImageWithURL(URL)` together with the *AutoPurgingImageCache* from [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage).

How can I be informed that `af_setImageWithURL` fetched the image, so I can put it into my cache? Because this is done in Background.

I'd prefer something like: `imageView.af_imageFromCache(URL)` which sets the image from cache if it is already in there or otherwise downloads async, then sets the image and saves it in the cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shared `ImageDownloader` that the `UIImageView` uses already puts the image into the `AutoPurgingImageCache` automatically. Every time you use the `imageView.af_setImageWithURL(URL)` it will attempt to pull the image out of the image cache if it exists. If the image is not already in the cache, it will start the download on the `ImageDownloader` instance.

Comment: That explains a lot! Is there a way to get the shared `ImageDownloader` object if I need to fetch an image out of it manually for different use than adding it to an `UIView`?

Comment: I created a new thread for that new question [right here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318935/alamofire-image-fetch-image-from-autopurgingimagecache-after-af-setimagewithurl)

Comment: (edit) I feel as though the cache doesn't work if a filter is applied. Is there a way to cache the filtered image?

Comment: @achi we have [tests](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/blob/master/Tests/UIImageViewTests.swift#L182-L202) verifying that it does work correctly. If you think there really is an issue, if you could put together another test that verifies the bug, that would be awesome!

Comment: Might you clarify - is the image cached before or after the filter is applied?

Comment: It's cached after the filter is applied. The `UIImageView` extension uses the `ImageDownloader` to first download the image "AND" run the filter is one exists. After the filter is run on the image, it is added to the cache, then returned to the `UIImageView` extension to be applied to the image view with whatever image transition was specified.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 4.0**

Set 'AutoPurgingImageCache' in Appdelegate so that i can access it in any class

var  imageCache:AutoPurgingImageCache?

```
   imageCache = AutoPurgingImageCache(
        memoryCapacity: 100_000_000,
        preferredMemoryUsageAfterPurge: 60_000_000
    )
```

Then set image in my service class

```
class func setImage(url : String,imageview:UIImageView) {

    let imageCache = appDelegate.imageCache!
    // Fetch
    if let cachedAvatar = imageCache.image(withIdentifier: url){
         imageview.image = cachedAvatar
    }else {

        Alamofire.request(url).responseImage { response in
            debugPrint(response)
            debugPrint(response.result)
            if let image = response.result.value {
                imageview.image = image
                // Add
                imageCache.add(image, withIdentifier: url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```