# Alamofire Image: Fetch Image from AutoPurgingImageCache after af_setImageWithURL()

Tags: ios, image, swift, caching, alamofire

I use AlamofireImage in my project. I use `someImageView.af_setImageWithURL(url)` a lot.

However at some point I need to fetch an image manually from the imageCache, because I do not want to apply it to an UIImageView.

This brings up 2 problems:

1. I can access the image cache directly by creating one with `let imageCache = AutoPurgingImageCache()`. Is this **the same cache** as `.af_setImageWithURL()` uses (Singleton)? Or is this a new one? Which is worthless in my case, because I could not profit from the prefilled cache.
2. Given this is the same cache: How can I fetch the correct image? I thought about `imageCache.imageForRequest(NSUrlRequest)`. Will this match on the images I downloaded before with `.af_setImageWithURL()` if the NSUrlRequest does use the same NSURL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Question 1

That is not the same cache that `UIImageView` uses. If you need access the same cache, you can do so by `UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader.imageCache`.

### Question 2

You will need to use the exact same `NSURLRequest` and the same `ImageFilter`. If you use the same `NSURLRequest` and the same `ImageFilter`, the image will be directly fetched from the cache if it exists. If you are using a different `ImageFilter`, then the original image will most likely be pulled from the `NSURLCache`, then the `ImageFilter` will be run over it, placed into the `AutoPurgingImageCache` and returned. If the `NSURLRequest` is different, the new image will need to be downloaded again.

Comment: What is the best method for download a bunch of images and caching them? Do i just imageDownloader.downloadImage(URLRequest: urlRequest) and then cache it afterward as state in the "Add / Remove / Fetch Images" section of your documentation? If this is what i have to do, then do i have to cache each image with a unique identifier?

Comment: Downloading a bunch of images before you need to display them can be done with the `downloadImages` API on the `ImageDownloader`. Then, once you are going to display the images, you can use the `UIImageView` extension methods. If the image has already been cached, it will simply load from the cache and be displayed. If it has not yet been downloaded, it is added to the queue. If it is in the middle of being downloaded, the `UIImageView` download request will attach itself to the already in-flight download.

Comment: This will download images from array of URLs and cache them in-memory.
<br/>
```
let imageDownloader = ImageDownloader()
var URLRequests = [URLRequestConvertible]()
URLRequests.append(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://some/image/some.png")!))
```
<br/>
. As @cnoon mentioned, to set an image use ```myUIImageView.af_setImageWithURL(imageUrl)```. 
<br/>
This will load image from cache if present. If it doesn't exist, then network call will happen

Comment: Is there a way to consolidate the ImageCache that lives within the UIImageView.af_setImage() with images from non-UIImageView requests to live within the same cache? The only way I see this is possible for now is to access the UIImageView's cache `UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader.imageCache` to read and write to it directly? @cnoon

Answer (score 1):

This is answer to the comment: How to download multiple images, save them to cache and get from cache.

Following code will download images from array of URLs and cache them in-memory.

`let imageDownloader = ImageDownloader()
var URLRequests = [URLRequestConvertible]()
URLRequests.append(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://some/image/some.png")!))`


As @cnoon mentioned, to set an image use `myUIImageView.af_setImageWithURL(imageUrl)`

**This will load image from cache if present. If it doesn't exist, then network call will happen**